# PyCharm does not show red points (breakpoints)

Tags: ide, pycharm, breakpoints

Pycharm does not show red points, you can see it on my screenshots:

[Before I click to set up a breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yzwG.png)

[After I click to set up a breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYI7i.png)

Comment: Hello, can you specify a bit more? Where do you click to set up the breakpoint? Have you tried restarting Pycharm?

Comment: Hello! I click the area between row number and code. I outlined the area by red square, you can check it on my screenshot [screen_1](https://pp.userapi.com/c852024/v852024723/84ea9/u9bnyohPF2E.jpg)
And after I click there: [screen_2](https://pp.userapi.com/c852024/v852024723/84eb0/Jg09tTN4-xM.jpg)
Finally, what I expect (took screenshot from the Internet): [screen_3](https://pp.userapi.com/c852024/v852024723/84eb7/z_0JpTvT03E.jpg)

Comment: It could come from the fact Pycharm does not detect your file as being a Python file. However, as the word highlighting work, I doubt it is the reason of your issue...